# Como crear una variable cookie usando leptos o wasm

Tags: rust

Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo un fremawork para frontend en rust llamado leptos, y todo iba muy bien hasta que tuve la necesidad de crear una cookie, estuve investigando en la documentación, pero al parecer no hay nada relacionado con esto, ¿hay alguna forma de crear cookies ya sea en leptos o usando WASM?.

De ante mano muchas gracias, saludos.